# how std::thread constructor detects rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, constructor, perfect-forwarding

Obviously it is possible to pass an rvalue reference to `std::thread` constructor. My problem is with definition of this constructor in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). It says that this constructor:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

> Creates new std::thread object and associates it with a thread of
>   execution. First the constructor copies/moves all arguments (both the
>   function object f and all args...) to thread-accessible storage as if
>   by the function:

```
template <class T>
typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

As far as I can check:

```
std::is_same<int, std::decay<int&&>::type>::value
```

returns true. This means `std::decay<T>::type` will drop rvalue reference part of argument. Then how `std::thread` constructor knows that which argument is passed by lvalue or rvalue references? Because all `T&` and `T&&` will be converted to `T` by `std::decay<T>::type`

Comment: "Applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer implicit conversions to the type T, removes cv-qualifiers, and defines the resulting type as the member typedef type" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay  - where do you see that it drops references?

Comment: @xaxxon you are missing `::type`.

Comment: @T.C. removed -- but why are they the same?

Comment: @xaxxon That's the "lvalue-to-rvalue" part.

Comment: I see.  it's not the rvalue that's going to an lvalue, it's the int going to an int&&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto s = std::decay_copy(std::string("hello"));
```

Is equivalent to:

```
template<>
std::string std::decay_copy<std::string>(std::string&& src) {
    return std::string(std::move(src));
}

std::string s = decay_copy<std::string>(std::string("hello"));
```

Comment: @xaxxon more or less. It'm trying to demonstrate the result of the template expansion.

Answer (score 5):

The `std::thread` constructor knows the value category of its arguments, because it knows what `Function` and `Args...` are, which it uses to perfectly forward the its parameters to `decay_copy` (or equivalent).

The actual thread function doesn't know the value category. It's always invoked as an rvalue, with all rvalue arguments - which makes sense: the copies of `f` and `args...` are local to the thread, and won't be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It is common problem of the perfect forwarding. If you want to restore information about rvalue in the function, you have to use std::forward [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) . If you are interested in the value type detection you may read this [value_category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)  . From the description you can find the information how the compiler recognizes rvalue, xvalue, lvalue, prvalue, gvalue on compile time.