# C++ Curious case of passing typename/datatype name/class name to thread constructor

Tags: c++, declaration

I have returned to c++ after long years of Java/Node.js programming so, I am out of touch with the templates (I am working on that).

While revising concurrency, I accidentally stumbled upon the following case

```
class Test
{
};

int main()
{
  std::thread t(Test);
}
```

What I was experimenting with was, what if I pass a non-callable object and then I would study the error and source code. But I accidentally passed the type name. The program compiled an ran with no issue and I was baffled.

Then I tried something more stupid

```
int main()
{
  std::thread t1(int);
}
```

And somehow it worked as well.
Though these two cases compiled and ran properly. I don't get how.
If it tried `t.join()` or `t1.join()` I get following compilation error

```
t.join() cannot be resolved
```

I just simply just don't get what is happening in these two cases and how t.join() could not be resolved.

**My research on it so far**

I spend a significant amount of time trying to figure out how the compiler would have figured out whether the given value is callable. I came across this link: [find out if a C++ object is callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393938/find-out-if-a-c-object-is-callable) 
It made a lot of sense because of member detection idiom but when I checked the source of gcc it seemed it used `std::_Bind_simple` of functional header/library to figure this out. But it didn't solve my query.
Then, this post [how std::thread constructor detects rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242552/how-stdthread-constructor-detects-rvalue-reference) asked the similar question but the answer made no sense to me.

Any sort of assistance will be very appreciated

Comment: declaration of function in local scope.

Comment: Oh!! I have been victim to most vexing parse. If possible could you elaborate how the parsing is happing in this case.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I won't say most vexing parse, as I don't see other way to parse it :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I totally forgot about the declaration in local scope. I am really rusty.

Comment: I don't see why this is getting downvoted. It shows thought and effort and is expressed very clearly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for concern bro but the error is quite foolish. I am really quite embarrassed.

Comment: @Dr.Xperience: It is not foolish. I've been studying and using C++ for about 12 years now, and I still make this mistake every now and then.

Comment: @Dr.Xperience It's still a good question. Remember that questions on Stack Overflow stay up for future readers. And you are probably not the only person to have made this mistake. Local function declarations are one of the great [gotcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming))s of c++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Wow, I hope someday I could say same

Comment: Oh, and I just realised that this is an especially devious case of the most vexing parse, because if you forget to `join` or `detach`, then you might easily be tricked into believing that a thread was actually started.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm, I didn't thought. Good insight. Though net is very cruel.

Comment: @ChristianHackl That is exactly what I thought initally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Jaroda42 what I was doing was making a function declaration in local scope.

```
std::thread t(Test);
```

Where function being being `t` return type be `std::thread` and parameters being class type `Test`.

It was really stupid but this is what one get if one leaves a language for long time.